# Fitting polynomial to 35 orders of data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fits

I have 3 data files; wavelength/pixels, counts/pixels, and background/pixels. Each data files  multiple order (total number of orders = 35). I need to fit a polynomial to each order of *background/pixels* and then calculate *counts/background* for each order and plot wavelength -vs- counts/background. This is what I have done so far

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits

# Load and open FITS files
counts_image = ("counts.fits")
wavelength_image = ("wavelength.fits")
background_image = ("backgound.fits")

sp = fits.open(counts_image)
sp_w = fits.open(wavelength_image)
sp_b = fits.open(background_image)

# Array data
counts = np.array(sp[0].data)
wave = np.array(sp_w[0].data)
background = np.array(sp_b[0].data)

# Perform fit for each order number (0-34)
order_number = 27 

# 4th order polynomial
coeffs = np.polyfit(wave[order_number],backgound[order_number], deg=4)
poly = np.poly1d(coeffs)
yp = np.polyval(poly,wave[order_number])
plt.plot(wave[order_number],yp)

# Counts/background fit
counts_fit = counts[order_number]/yp

# Plotting
plt.figure()
plt.plot(wave[order_number],counts_fit)
```

Now this works for one order number. How can I extend the order to fit all 35 orders producing a single plot? I am new to python so any help and advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: A figure is implicitly created when you call `plt.plot()` for the first time, then everything is, by default, plotted on the same figure. So create a loop, do not create a new figure after each iteration and after the loop call `plt.show()` to display the result.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking I needed a loop but I am sure where to start. Would I start the loop before the fit? At the moment I am thinking the start of the loop could be something like **`for x in range np.shape(wave):`** But I am confused how to apply to the polynomial fit and store the results.

Comment: From the title I thought you were trying to fit a 35 degree polynomial to your data.  Here the number 35 in the title is not so relevant =)

Comment: You can also use the polynomial1d model from [`astropy.modeling`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/index.html).  It's using Numpy+Scipy under the hood.  But last I worked on it at least it was possible to fit a set of stacked arrays simulatenously.

Comment: Thank you. Do I stack the arrays before fitting or after? Is this correct for stacking array before fitting `order_numbers = np.stack(background[0:34]`? Would I ned to create another array to store the results from the fit? I realise that these are basis questions but I am confused.

Comment: Yes I was unsure how best to word the title!

Comment: Got there eventually using a while loop and stacked arrays.